# zookeeper startup become slow and Hbase start up fails

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

suddenly, my zookeeper startup become slow, I check the log, and find  the

```
**1** Mon Apr  1 16:33:13 CST 2019 Starting zookeeper on hadoop11
**2** core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
      data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
      scheduling priority             (-e) 0
      file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
      pending signals                 (-i) 2065499
      max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
      max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
      open files                      (-n) 1024
      pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
      POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
      real-time priority              (-r) 0
      stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
      cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
      max user processes              (-u) 102400
      virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
      file locks                      (-x) unlimited
**3** 2019-04-01 16:33:34,280 INFO  [main] quorum.QuorumPeer: Resolved hostname: hbase1 to address: hbase1/127.0.0.1
```

the time interval of log#1 and log#3 is 23s.

In the normal case, the time interval is only 3s.

the slow ZK will make HMaster startup fails:

```
2019-04-01 16:33:35,341 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:3201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:3212)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException: master:160000x0, quorum=hadoop11:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Unexpected KeeperException creating base node
```

I have no idea about the slow case. Previous ZK is ok, but it suddenly become unable to startup quickly.

Comment: Why are you starting HBase before ZooKeeper is up?

Comment: start-hbase.sh script start ZK first, the start HMaster and RS.

Comment: You could set HBASE_SLAVE_SLEEP to delay the hbase daemons.  See https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/bin/zookeepers.sh#L53.